# jQuery: copying element attributes to another attribute of the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of links, all in the same class, each with a custom argument ("switch-text"). My script should copy the text of the custom argument to the text of each link and replace it ("Pick A" should become "Pick A Please").

It works fine with only 1 link, but when I add several, they all get switched to the first argument. ("Pick B" should be replaced by "Pick B Please", but it doesn't).

I could probably solve this using each(), but I'm preferably looking for a simple, single jQuery line that does it, and I'm baffled I haven't yet found out how to achieve this.

Can somebody help? Thanks!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".switcher").text( $(".switcher").attr("switch-text") );
});
</script>
<a href="a" class="switcher" switch-text="Pick A Please">Pick A</a><br>
<a href="b" class="switcher" switch-text="Pick B Please">Pick B</a><br>
```

Comment: I suggest you use `.data()` instead of your so called custom arguments http://api.jquery.com/data/ and is `Pick A Please` with `Pick A`, the same pattern for all?.. cause there is a better code for that, if that is the case....

Comment: I looked into .data(). Unfortunately it cannot read custom tags without installing a jQuery plugin first, and I'm trying to keep bandwith low.

The arguments will vary without any pattern, so I cannot optimize this, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *each* to go through all the elements, and use *this* to always act on the current one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".switcher").each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).attr("switch-text") );
  });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ofigi/)

---

**Without jQuery**
you need:

- [Dean Edwards document ready](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/)
- [getElementsByClassName](http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass/)

Code:

```
readyList.push(function() {
  var els = getElementsByClassName("switcher");
  for ( var i = els.length; i--; ) {
    els[i].innerHTML = els[i].getAttribute("switch-text");
  }
});
```

And change Dean's script to execute functions on document.ready:

```
function init() {
  // ...
  // do stuff
  for ( var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++ ) {
    if ( typeof readyList[i] === "function" ) {
      readyList[i]();
    }
  }
  //..
}
```

That's it. You've saved a lot of bandwidth. :)

### [Demo without jQuery](http://jsbin.com/ofigi/2/edit)

---

Comment: Thank you. Is this the simplest version? Isn't there a way to chain everything together in 1 line?

I'm asking because I will have many many lines similar to this and every byte will count.

Comment: there is a simple version **if every line counts: DONT USE JQUERY**